# Tapestry generates input tags in pair

Tags: java, forms, textfield, tapestry

I want to generate HTML5 valid document, but I have a problem with forms in my Tapestry app. I am using tapestry textfields like below:

```
<t:textfield t:id="specId" value="val" />
```

Tapestry generates html input element:

```
<input id="specId" name="specId" type="text"></input>
```

But element input is not valid in pair (with end tag `</input>`) and html validator yells: "Error: Stray end tag input.".

Is any way how to generate input tags in single form like 
`<input .../>` ?

Comment: What version of Tapestry do you use? I use the latest (5.3.7) and get as result the same, but without end tag.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-2071

Comment: My version of Tapestry is 5.3.6. By Nathan post the bug have been fixed in 5.4 version (and affected version in 5.3.6). So apparently I need to increase my Tapestry version. Thanks you both for answers!

Comment: I don't think 5.4 is released yet. But there is 5.3.7 which has been released recently, and it seems it has been fixed in that version.

Comment: Yes, I supposed you have right. I am going to try the 5.3.7 version. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can override MarkupWriterFactory service with its own MarkupModel that will abbreviate html5 void elements instead of rendering end tag.

```java
public class Html5MarkupModel extends AbstractMarkupModel {
    private static final Set<String> VOID_ELEMENTS = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(
            "area", "base", "br", "col", "command", "embed", "hr", "img", "input", "keygen", "link", "meta", "param", "source", "track", "wbr"
    ));

    public Html5MarkupModel(boolean useApostropheForAttributes) {
        super(useApostropheForAttributes);
    }

    public EndTagStyle getEndTagStyle(String element) {
        return VOID_ELEMENTS.contains(element) ? EndTagStyle.ABBREVIATE : EndTagStyle.REQUIRE;
    }

    public boolean isXML() {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Html5MarkupWriterFactory implements MarkupWriterFactory {

    private final PageContentTypeAnalyzer analyzer;
    private final RequestPageCache cache;

    private final MarkupModel htmlModel = new Html5MarkupModel(false);
    private final MarkupModel htmlPartialModel = new Html5MarkupModel(true);
    private final MarkupModel xmlModel = new XMLMarkupModel();
    private final MarkupModel xmlPartialModel = new XMLMarkupModel(true);

    public Html5MarkupWriterFactory(PageContentTypeAnalyzer analyzer, RequestPageCache cache) {
        this.analyzer = analyzer;
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    public MarkupWriter newMarkupWriter(ContentType contentType) {
        return newMarkupWriter(contentType, false);
    }

    public MarkupWriter newPartialMarkupWriter(ContentType contentType) {
        return newMarkupWriter(contentType, true);
    }

    public MarkupWriter newMarkupWriter(String pageName) {
        return newMarkupWriter(analyzer.findContentType(cache.get(pageName)));
    }

    private MarkupWriter newMarkupWriter(ContentType contentType, boolean partial) {
        boolean isHTML = contentType.getMimeType().equalsIgnoreCase("text/html");

        MarkupModel model = partial
                ? (isHTML ? htmlPartialModel : xmlPartialModel)
                : (isHTML ? htmlModel : xmlModel);

        // The charset parameter sets the encoding attribute of the XML declaration, if
        // not null and if using the XML model.

        return new MarkupWriterImpl(model, contentType.getCharset());
    }
}
```

And service override contribution:

```java
@Contribute(ServiceOverride.class)
public void contributeServiceOverrides(MappedConfiguration<Class, Object> configuration,
                                       ObjectLocator objectLocator) {
    // use proxy instead of real service instance
    // to prevent recursion on initialization cycle
    configuration.add(MarkupWriterFactory.class,
            objectLocator.proxy(MarkupWriterFactory.class, Html5MarkupWriterFactory.class));
}
```